# trigger on change event getting value from url

Tags: jquery

i have this URL

```
http://localhost/rge/main-rtl/weekeventinfo.php?mon=07
```

and this is my select tag

```
      <select name="month" id="month" class="form-control">
                                        <option selected disabled>אנא בחר חודש</option>
                                        <option value="01">ינואר</option>
                                        <option value="02">פברואר</option>
                                        <option value="03">מרץ</option>
                                        <option value="04">אפריל</option>
                                        <option value="05">מאי</option>
                                        <option value="06">יוני</option>
                                        <option value="07">יולי</option>
                                        <option value="08">אוגוסט</option>
                                        <option value="09">ספטמבר</option>
                                        <option value="10">אוקטובר</option>
                                        <option value="11">נובמבר</option>
                                        <option value="12">דצמבר</option>
                                    </select>
```

my goal is to trigger an onchange event on page load that will select the value from the dropdown list i did manage to display the value in the dropdown but the trigger of the on change didn't happen. i am getting the value but the select action is not triggered.

this is my script

```js
     $('#month').on('change', function() {
          selectmonth();
      });

      function selectmonth() {

          var m = "<?= $_GET['mon'] ?>";
      $("#month").val(m)
      }

      $(document).ready(function() {
          selectmonth();

      })
```

when I change a value manually the change event is triggering an ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '#filter', function () {

        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'main-table.php',
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function() {

                $('.preloader').show();

            },
            success: (
                function (data) {
                    $(".result").html(data);
                    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
                        style: 'btn-info',

                    });
                    $('.preloader').hide();
                }
            )
        });
        return false;
    });




})
```

Comment: Your `$(document).on('change', '#filter', function()` is applied to an element with id `filter`, but your dropdown has id `month`.

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, changing a value doesn't produce any event, but you can [`trigger`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) it manually using the aptly named function. Besides, you'll have to wait until the event handlers have been setup, because as it stands now, there are no handlers for the change event. You can do it by rearranging your code a bit.

```js
// Such simple function could be executed inline
function selectmonth() {
  var m = "02";
  $("#month").val(m).trigger('change');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#month', function() {  // Changed this target to match the form
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    // Handle ajax call
    console.log(data);
  });

  // Delay the trigger until the handlers are setup
  selectmonth();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="month" id="month" class="form-control">
  <option selected disabled>אנא בחר חודש</option>
  <option value="01">ינואר</option>
  <option value="02">פברואר</option>
</select>
```